# Android Image Unexpectedly Shifts after using setImageResource

Tags: android, imageview, overlay, android-xml, android-framelayout

I have been experiencing unexpected image behavior, within a framelayout.
When I change a picture with setImageResource, the image moves unexpectedly (and, for some reason, slighty enlarges).

My code in Java is simply:

```
myImage.setImageResource(myImageID);
```

The new picture is of the exact same dimension and format (they are simply circles, with no difference other than color, and I have successfully been changing them with setImageResource elsewhere in the program without issue).

**Here is the before picture:**

Blue - what I am changing.

Yellow - a circle that blue is overlaying.

Cyan - a circle that is overlaid on the very top of both.

[image]

**Here is the after picture** (notice that the change was successful, as it is now magenta, but it shifted to the left, and slightly grew for some reason).

[image]

**Here is an excerpt from my XML:** ( I am changing the id/p4_av)

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/p4"
                android:padding="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/p4_halo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:src="@drawable/halo"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/p4_av"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/p4_bucket"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:src="@drawable/bucket"/>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Fruckubus Crunt
Here, is my suggestion use android:scaleType = "center Crop" or "fitXY". It might fix the issue.

Comment: fitXY actually made the image the same size as the other, yellow one, and it still shifted.
centerCrop clipped the sides, and it still shifted. But thanks for your answer. I believe I've solved this, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is a bunch of newbie mistakes all rolled into one.

Initially, the yellow circle png was slightly larger than the avatar to be changed. This worked fine up until it had to change, then it started to get weird.

Instead, I just added margins and changed the ImageView width.

Also, there was some other oddness left over from earlier development.
The original XML entry has been changed (along with its siblings) to:

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/p1_av"
                    android:layout_margin="15sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar"/>
```

As you can see, the width has been changed to match parent, and a layout_margin was introduced.

There was also a layout_weight that had been left-in from earlier. While I don't believe it was breaking anything, it was unnecessary and has been removed.

And that's it. It now works perfectly.